# Gii doesn't recognize many-to-many relationship to itself?

Tags: sql, yii, yii2, gii

[image]

So I am trying to implement a friendlist, the above is the SQL diagram I made for my simple project and after generating the Models. I realized there was something wrong with the way Gii generated the model.

I wanted to make a many-to-many relationship with User to itself, but this is what I got:

```
class User {
...

    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['userId' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Friend {
...

    public function getFriend()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Member::className(), ['id' => 'friendId']);
    }
}
```

The User class doesn't have any relationship with itself, I expected something like getUsers() inside of User, but it didn't generate it. I initially thought about not making a model with the junction table, but I did so just to see what would happen. I don't think I need it. So I am not sure how to do this correctly? Do I need to get rid of my Junction Table Models and Do I need to make the relationship between User to itself and User to Message manually? I thought about doing a many-to-many in User and Message and a many-to-many in User for User. Is this the right thing? Tell me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a true way. You need a junction table for implementing your goal. Easily as you done this, you must define two model: `User` and `Friend`. Now on your `User` model at first you must define a relation for get the list of all friends, Suppose call it `getFriendsLists`:

```
public function getFriendsLists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::className(), ['userId' => 'id']);
}
```

This relation says that "Get me all account that are connected with me, i.e. if my id is `102`, this relation return all record of `friend` table that their `userId`s are `102`". Well, now we get all friends with a relation on `User` model, let call him `getFriends`:

```
public function getFriends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['friendId' => 'id']
                ->via('friendsList');
}
```

Notice that `'friendsList'` as is a parameter of `via` method, is our predefined relation on top of this answer. Now easily you can get all account that are friends of our example (User with id `102`):

```
public FriendController extends Controller
{
    // Some code goes here!
    public function actionFriendList($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOne($id);
        $friends = $user->friends;

        return $this->render('friend-list', ['friendsArray' => $friends]);
    }
}
```

And use them on your `friend-list` view file as `$friendsArray` variable. Extra note that `$user->friends` use `friends` relation that you defined on `User` model with `getFriends` method.

Comment: Is the plural on the getFriendsLists required? You omitted the plural in friendsList.

Comment: what does friendsList refer to?

Comment: No! it's just a php function name, you can name it something like `meysam` or `getLovelyDays` or anything you want! Naming a variable just have semantic sense. / I suggest you to `var_dump` all this function and see their content ;).